# difference between session and _session (facebook integration)

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

i download the code for facebook integration...and my application work fine..

i just wants to know that what is difference between **session** and **_session**

and also **loginDialog** and **_loginDialog**

thanks for help...:)

```
@interface MyFbViewController :UIViewController <FBSessionDelegate, FBRequestDelegate>
{


FBSession* _session;

FBLoginDialog *_loginDialog;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) FBSession *session;

@property (nonatomic, retain) FBLoginDialog *loginDialog;


@end
```

in MyFbViewController.m file.........

```
@synthesize session = _session;

@synthesize loginDialog = _loginDialog;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_session` and `_loginDialog` are instance variables of the class. As such you are completely responsible for memory management (i.e. retaining and releasing) those variables as you would be with any other variable.

The properties session and loginDialog in combination with the `synthesize` statement generate two class properties, which in turn are only special selectors.

`@synthesize session = _session;` basically generates two methods, `- (FBSession *)session;` and `- (void)setSession:(FBSession *)newSession;` which are invoked whenever you use the dot-notation for object properties (i.e. `object.session`). You could write them on your own and leave out the synthesize but that is seldomly done because you again would be responsible for memory management.

As these properties are `retain` properties, the automatically generated methods handle the necessary retain/release stuff and could look something like this:

```
- (FBSession *)session
{
    return _session;
}

- (void)setSession:(FBSession *)newSession
{
    if (newSession != _session)
    {
        [_session release];
        [newSession retain];
        _session = newSession;
    }
}
```

Which frees you from the burden of memory management as long as you set the property to `nil` when done (as this will release any existing object).

Answer (score 0):

Your properties almost always have a backing variable. What

@synthesize session = _session;
does is declare that the backing variable for your search bar will be called _session. This allows you to decouple the name of the property from the name of your variable. In fact, if you don't use @synthesize you don't need to have a backing variable at all.

It avoid clashes with variable names and
make it clear when I'm using a local variable and when I'm using an instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

_session is your variable. session is your accessor.

You can write `_session` or `self.session` but can't write `self._session` or just `session`.

But `_session` and `self.session` are not doing the same thing. `self.session` call the generated getter or setters with the property params.

For sample nonatomic,retain generate a setter like that:

```
- (void) setSession:(FBSession*)session
{
  if(_session != session) {
    [_session release];
    _session = [session retain];
  }
}
```

This code manage memory for you. If you use _session directly the old value is never released (and leak) and the new value isn't retained.

The _ before session mean that this variable is private and that you haven't to access it directly

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, there is a *property* named `session` and an *instance variable* named `_session`.  Properties have automatically generated accessor (if you `@synthesize` them). They can be accessed either using the dot-syntax (`self.session`) or by using the setter and getter (`[self setSession:yourSession]` / `[self session]`. This property uses a backstore (as properties do not store information by themselves, they just provide an interface to access data) named `_session`. These accessor take care of memory management so you should really use only these.

Enough blah blah: Most of the time, if you have a property you should use it. So use `self.session` instead of `_session` in your code.

More on properties in the always famous iOS developer library: [The Objective-C Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1)