# initWithName in objective c

Tags: c++, objective-c, properties

I am trying to translate from objective c to c++. But have some objective c sintax not clear for me. Help me plz to understand what is this:

```
@synthesize contrast = _contrast;
```

I think this generates getter setter for property named contrast
But what is _contrast? I have not found it anywhere in project except one place (below)

then in another function:

```
_firstParameter = [ [ MPPostProcessParameter alloc ] initWithName: @"Contrast" minValue: 0.4f maxValue: 2.0f defaultValue: 1.0f ];
```

Ok. Here I think we initialize this property named contrast (see above) which contains constructor for  MPPostProcessParameter (minValue: 0.4f maxValue: and so on)
BUT! 
in other function this contrast property used as float! Not an object of MPPostProcessParameter type!

```
function (xxx, _contrast); //? the second argument must be float!
```

Help me plz to understand what is write in

```
_firstParameter = [ [ MPPostProcessParameter alloc ] initWithName: @"Contrast" minValue: 0.4f maxValue: 2.0f defaultValue: 1.0f ];
```

on c++ language (what is  initWithName and what this function done at all)
Thank you

Comment: I think the problem with `_firstParameter` is not clear because the `MPPostProcessParameter` object is not stored within the `_contrast` variable (as your question suggests) but rather in `_firstParameter`. Are you sure all snippets are correct?

Answer (score 0):

On the first issue: This statement does generate getter/setter methods for the property `contrast`. I described some of it in [difference between session and _session (facebook integration)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240599/difference-between-session-and-session-facebook-integration/8240713#8240713) `_contrast` here is the name of the (internal) instance variable that is being created for this property. Although you can declare the instance variable yourself in the class declaration you do not have to. If you use the `synthesize` statement this way, the compiler will generate a instance variable for you. Also if you just use `@synthesize contrast;` without specifying an instance variable name, the instance variable will have the same name as the property (and getter method) which is no issue in objective C.